# Why does summation of string and number output a string but multiplication of them output a number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**string + number**

```
const a = "5";
const b = 7;

console.log(a + b);
```

**Output is -**
57

---

**string * number**

```
const a = "5";
const b = 7;

console.log(a * b);
```

**Output is -**
35

Comment: `+` in JavaScript can mean multiple things when used with two operands - addition, or concatenation. String concatenation is used if one of the operands is a string. Whereas for `*`, this doesn't have two meanings as `+` does, it simply just means try and multiply, regardless of the types

Comment: Relevant specification: [ApplyStringOrNumericBinaryOperator](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-applystringornumericbinaryoperator).

Answer (score 0):

it's based on what the creators of JS thought would be more useful. In every other language you can concatenate the strings, numbers and other stuff using the `+`. So in JS they thought that would be a nice solution as well. But then... what does it mean to multiply a string? The creators of JS had no answer, so assumed this must be a mathematical operation.